# Defining a group by means of translations

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $R$ be a non empty set and $T$ be a subset of functions $R\to R$ (we call them translations) which satisfies the following:

1. the identity map $t(x)=x$ is in $T$
2. given $x,y\in R$ there exists one and only one function $t_{xy}\in T$ such that $t_{xy}(x)=y$.
3. if $t,s\in T$ then $t\circ s\in T$.

Now fix any element $0\in R$ and define a addition operation as
$$
 x + y = t_{0y}(x)
$$
where $t_{0y}$ is the only map in $T$ such that $t_{0y}(0)=y$.

I'm able to prove that $(R,0,+)$ is a group. Is it commutative?

Comment: In (2) I guess you meant to write "given $x,y \in {\color{red}{R}}$ there exists one and only one function $t_{xy}$..."?

Comment: @IvoTerek corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think so.

Let $G$ be an nonabelian group and denote the group operation by $\bullet$. The set of left-multiplications $T=\{L_g:G\rightarrow G, h \mapsto g\bullet h \mid g \in G\}$ is a set of translations.

Indeed $\operatorname{id} = L_e \in T$, $L_g,L_h \in T \implies L_g\circ L_h= L_{g\bullet h} \in T$ and given $x,y\in G$ we find that $L_{y\bullet x^{-1}}$ defines a (unique by evaluating at $e$) translation.

Now for $x,y\in G$ we find that $x+y = L_y(x) = y\bullet x$ and $y+x = L_x(y) = x \bullet y$ won’t coincide in general, as we chose $G$ to be nonabelian.

Comment: Just to complement this great answer: the axioms also say that once $0 \in R$ is fixed, the map $R \mapsto G$ that takes $x \mapsto t_{0x}$ is a bijection, so the operation $+$ on $R$ is just the pull-back of the operation $\circ$. It's like $G$ is a group, but $R$ is an "affine group", in the sense that $G$ is to $R$ as the underlying translation space is to its affine space. So, in the same way that any vector space is an affine space, it makes sense to produce a counter example seeing a non-abelian group as a "affine group" over itself. Do note the quotes on "affine group", though.